# Printing multiline text file

Tags: php, html

I got a huge list in a text file like this:

```
Complete Name
Email
id

Complete Name
Email
id
```

So, what i want to do is print with php file each of these lines in a table:

```
 ----------------------- 
|Name  | email  |  id   |
 -----------------------
```

How can I do this? I can explode with a handler but i really don't know how to grep each field and each line.

Thanks.

Comment: are you going to print it in an html table or a text table as above?  Is this huge list consistently formed (i.e. those three blocks of information separated by a newline?)

Comment: You'll get a better and more helpful response if you show that you've taken some time to try to figure out a solution to your problem before asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shot in the dark:

```
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
fclose($fh);
echo "<table><tr><td>".str_replace(array("\n\n","\n"),array("</td></tr><tr><td>","</td><td>"),$theData)."</tr></table>";
```

Comment: You cannot concat an array and a string together, that doesn't work.

Comment: This doesn't quite work.  The HTML isn't right that gets printed.

Comment: `<table><tr>Complete Name</td><td>Email</td><td>id</tr><tr>Complete Name</td><td>Email</td><td>id</tr></table>`

Comment: This works amazing and the code is pretty short. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
  $fileLines = file("file.txt", FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $tmpArray = array();
    $index = 0;
    $GROUP_SIZE =3;
    for($i = 0; $i< count($fileLines); $i++)
    {
       if ($index < $GROUP_SIZE){
         $tmpArray[] = array
         (
            "Name" => $fileLines[$i],
            "Email" => $fileLines[$i + 1],
            "id" => $fileLines[$i + 2],
         );
          $index =0;
       }   
       $index++;   
    }
```

now print $tmpArray should by easy (not tested :)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `explode` to get each group of text, then `explode` again to get each piece of data.

```
$str = <<<END
Complete Name
Email
id

Complete Name
Email
id
END;

$arr = explode("\r\n\r\n", $str);
foreach($arr as $x){
  list($name, $email, $id) = explode("\r\n", $x);
  echo $name;
  echo $email;
  echo $id;
}
```

Comment: @bopjesvla: I'm not doing all the work for him, this is a starting point, printing a table is up to him.  If he gets stuck doing that he can ask.

Comment: It's harder to start with this than provide the full solution :P

Comment: It works in a different way, and you're right, I just wanted the php code :) thanks for your time!